# What happens with running job processes when Heroku restarts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I read Heroku's [guide on dyno cycling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos), but I'm still a little confused as to what happens to running job processes when a dyno cycles/restarts.

The guide says Heroku's dynos restart at least once a day.

I have a rails app that runs fairly lengthy background jobs. What happens to a job that's processing in the background when a worker dyno get's cycled/restarted? Does that process just get killed if it doesn't end before those 30 seconds after the SIGTERM signal?

Also, do jobs stay in the queue during those 30 seconds, and get started only on the next dyno? Or can a job that's waiting on the queue get started during this time, like maybe 5 seconds before the SIGKILL signal?

Finally, does the ["preboot"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot) feature guarantee that no process is ever killed mid-process?

Thanks.